# Accidentally deleted the Downloads folder

Tags: command-line, directory, restore

I deleted the default downloads folder by accident using the terminal, is there a way to create a new default system folder for downloads?

Answer (score 5):

Create the Downloads folder again. Then open the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in your editor and make sure that the line for the Downloads folder is there, and that it reads

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
```

Save the file, log out and log back in: now, the Downloads folder should be there again and have its "special status" back.

*Some specifics in case it is needed:* `.config` is a hidden folder in your home folder. Activate "Show hidden files" to see hidden files and folders. You can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to toggle between seeing and hiding "hidden files and folders".

Comment: That works. Thanks!